# Assign template<derived> to a template<base> variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector

I have a template class that replaces direct construction of objects with just storing them for future purpose.

```
template<typename T>
typedef struct Construction{
     int arg;
} Construction;
```

Now I want to pass a `std::vector< Construction< Base > >` to a function that should then call the constructors of every Element with the given argument.

This works when I only use the base type, but as soon as I try to mix base and derived types, problems emerge:

```
Construction<Base> construct = Construction<Derived>(5);
```

This won't work, while a regular assignment like `Base& b = Derived(5);` does.

*Why does this not work?*

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this can be done in C++. "Derived" may derive from "Base" but "Construction<Derived>" doesn't derive from "Constrution<Base>". Also, you don't need the typedef -this is C++, not C.

Comment: **Stop!**: `Base b = Derived(5);` may work, but this is [Object Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) and should be avoided in general. Just because it compiles does not mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `Base& b`. Editing now.

Comment: As it has turned out, your real problem was much more than "why does this not work?". It was also "*given that this does not work, how do I ...?*". If you edit your question accordingly (including the title), it won't be a duplicate any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a lazy factory pattern. As you say in a comment, `Constr<Base>` does not hold enough information to construct a `Derived`. So when storing in a vector, you should use pointers rather than values. If you are willing to use the free store for the final objects, one solution is the following:

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct Derived : public Base { Derived(int x) : Base{x} { } };

template<typename T>
struct Constr;

template<>
struct Constr<Base> {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> make() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constr : Constr<Base> {
    int arg;
    Constr(int arg) : arg{arg} { }
    std::unique_ptr<Base> make() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>(arg);
    }
};

int main() {
    Constr<Derived> a{5}, b{2}, c{8};
    std::vector<Constr<Base>*> v{&a, &b, &c};

    // later...
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> u;
    for (auto& i : v)
        u.push_back(i->make());
    for (auto& i : u)
        std::cout << i->x << " ";  // 5 2 8
}
```

For this to work, we now make `Constr<Derived>` *derive* `Constr<Base>`. So we can use pointers/references to such objects following the same rules as pointers/references to `Base`/`Derived`, without defining any special constructors.

Note the forward declaration of `Constr`: this is needed because specialization `Const<Base>` needs to be defined *before* the general template; in turn, this is needed because the latter implicitly instantiates the former (by deriving it).

I cannot think of a simple solution without the free store, though. The only possibility is to use a raw memory buffer, either as a data member of `Constr<Base>`, or passed as an argument to `make()`. But this needs some work and will always have an upper bound on the size of `Derived`. Or, we could automatically choose between stack/free store depending on object size; this is generic but needs even more work.

Comment: Wow. That's exactly what I needed! Is there a specific reason why you use `{}` for initialization instead of `()` whenever possible? And why do we need the `override` keyword in this case?

Comment: @iFreilicht Nice to know! `{}` is just a habit. It's typically safer that `()` because it prevents narrowing conversions. But careful, when you use it on unknown types there may be surprises with types defining their own `initializer_list` constructors (like `std::vector`). In such cases, better use `()`.

Comment: @iFreilicht Thinking again about my solution, `Constr<T>` might drive any other concrete base class, e.g. `Constr_base`. In this case you don't need a specialization, so you don't need a forward declaration either. That's simpler, but otherwise equivalent.

Comment: I like the solution as it is. It's not integrated into my solution quite yet, but as soon as it is and it works, I will accept your answer. You were really, really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

It does not work, because instantiations of class templates are not related via a subclass-superclass relationship, even if the types, used in the instantiation are.

In many cases you can solve the problem, by providing a constructor template and/or assignment operator template to your original template, like:

```
struct Base {
    int x;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int y;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constr {
    T t;

    Constr() = default;

    template<typename U> Constr(const Constr<U> &a) : t(a.t) {}
};

int main() {
    Constr<Derived> a;
    Constr<Base> b = a;
    // Constr<Derived> c = b; // error, as it should
}
```

Comment: Good idea, and it works for other cases. But as I said, I use `Constr` to avoid instantiation of the Objects, they should be constructed later. And when I use this without `t`, the information which type a `Constr` object holds is lost. All `Constr` objects will be of type `Constr<Base>`.

Comment: How do you intend to convey to the actual constructors the information that `Construction<Base>` actually contains references to instances of `Derived`? Perhaps you use a virtual "factory" function for construction?

Comment: Yeah, factories are probably the way to go here.

Comment: `template<typename U> Constr& operator=(const Constr<U> &a)` :)